# Why does flask not accept the JWT Cookie?

Tags: python, flask, cookies, rest

I am trying to use Flask_JWT_Extended to secure my API.
If I send a request via swagger from 'localhost/api' to 'localhost/api/auth/check , it works.
But if I try to send it via JavaScript from 'localhost/CheckAuth.js', JWT Extended said that the access_token coockie is was not found.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix that?

My FLask Settings

```
# JWT settings
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = 'cookies'
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False
JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH = '127.0.0.1'
JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH = '/api/auth/refresh'
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = False
JWT_SECRET_KEY = 'changeme'
```

my Auth.py, there login and check are defined

```
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_restx import Resource
from api.mApi import api as marlinizer_api
from api.api_definition import login
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token, create_refresh_token, get_jwt_identity
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, jwt_refresh_token_required
from flask_jwt_extended import set_access_cookies, set_refresh_cookies
from database.operations import Users
from misc import security
from flask import escape

namespace = marlinizer_api.namespace('auth')


@namespace.route('/login')
class Login(Resource):
    @namespace.expect(login)
    def post(self):
        try:
            username = escape(request.json['username'])
            password = escape(request.json['password'])

            user = Users.get_user_by_username(username)
            if user is None or user['password'] != 
security.hash_user_password(str(password), str(user['salt'])):
            data = dict(login=False)
            return make_response(jsonify(**data), 200)

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=username)
        data = dict(login=True)
        resp = make_response(jsonify(**data), 200)
        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
        return resp

    except KeyError:
        return '{"login": "false"}', 400


@namespace.route('/refresh')
class Refresh(Resource):
    @jwt_refresh_token_required
    def post(self):
        user = get_jwt_identity()
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
        data = dict(refresh=True)
        resp = jsonify(**data)
        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        return make_response(resp, 200)


@namespace.route('/check')
class CheckAuth(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
        identity = get_jwt_identity()
        user = Users.get_user_by_username(identity)
        data = dict(auth=True)
        if user is None:
           data['auth'] = False
        return make_response(jsonify(**data), 200)
```

The JavaScript

```
    let client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check');
client.onload = function (x) {
    console.log(client.responseText);
}

client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
client.send('{}');
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem in Javascript.

Comment: I added my JavaScript

Comment: And where in that script so you send the JWT?

Comment: Nowhere. The JWT is included in the cookie, set in the login function in the auth python file.

Answer (score 0):

`JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH = '127.0.0.1'` is not doing what you think it's doing. This is for setting the url path for this cookie on the given domain, and should probably be something like `/` here. `JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN` (domain option in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie) and/or CORS is probably what you're looking for if your frontend is being served from a different sub domain then your backend.